# Partial Fractions help!?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, fractions, partial-fractions

$A + C = 0$

$-4A + B - 8C + D = 1$

$3A + 16C - 8D = -29$

$-12A + 3B + 16D = 5$

How do I equate the coefficients? Please provide steps an an explanation.

Comment: You have $4$ equations in $4$ unknowns. Write it in matrix form and use row operations, or just use the substitution or elimination methods that you would use for solving simultaneous equations.

Comment: Is it possible to see the initial fraction?

Answer (score 4):

Start with the first (and simplest) equation.

$A+C=0$ can be rearranged to give $C=-A$.

Substitute that into the other equations:

$-4A + B - 8C + D = 1 \Rightarrow -4A + B - 8(-A) + D = 1 \Rightarrow 4A+B+D=1$

$3A + 16C - 8D = -29 \Rightarrow 3A + 16(-A) - 8D = -29 \Rightarrow -13A - 8D = -29$

-12A + 3B + 16D = 5

Comment: Since you started with eliminating $C$ why not continue on the same idea. `−13A−8D=−29` This gives $D=(-13 A + 29) / 8\,$ so now there are only two equations left in two unknowns. Use either one to eliminate one of the remaining variables, then solve for the other.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 1&0\\ -4 &1&-8&1\\3 & 0 &16&-8\\-12&3&0&16 \end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}A\\B\\C\\D \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\-29\\5 \end{bmatrix}$$

This should help you. Find inverse of the matrix and multiply. Note $|P|\ne0$thus it is invertible. Where equation signifies $P$.$X$=$D$

Answer (score 1):

@tomi provides a quick and clever solution. The general solution process of @TheDeadLegend follows.

Form the augmented matrix.
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
  \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{I}
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr|cccc}
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -4 & 1 & -8 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 3 & 0 & 16 & -8 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 -12 & 3 & 0 & 16 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Gauss-Jordan reduction:

*Column 1*
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
  \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{I}
\end{array}
\right]_{1}
=
\left[
\begin{array}{rccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 4 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -3 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 12 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
  \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{I}
\end{array}
\right]_{0}
=
\left[
\begin{array}{ccrr|rccc}
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & -4 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 13 & -8 & -3 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 3 & 12 & 16 & 12 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

*Column 2*
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
  \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{I}
\end{array}
\right]_{2}
=
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{13} & 0 \\
 0 & -3 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
  \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{I}
\end{array}
\right]_{1}
=
\left[
\begin{array}{ccrr|rrrrc}
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & -4 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{8}{13} & -\frac{3}{13} & 0 & \frac{1}{13} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 24 & 13 & 0 & -3 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

*Column 3*
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
  \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{I}
\end{array}
\right]_{3}
=
\left[
\begin{array}{ccrc}
 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 4 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -24 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
  \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{I}
\end{array}
\right]_{2}
=
\left[
\begin{array}{cccr|rrrr}
 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{8}{13} & \frac{16}{13} & 0 & -\frac{1}{13} & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{19}{13} & \frac{40}{13} & 1 & \frac{4}{13} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{8}{13} & -\frac{3}{13} & 0 & \frac{1}{13} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{72}{361} & -\frac{39}{361} & -\frac{24}{361} & \frac{13}{361} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

*Column 4*
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
  \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{I}
\end{array}
\right]_{4}
=
\left[
\begin{array}{cccr}
 1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{8}{13} \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{19}{13} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{8}{13} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
  \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{I}
\end{array}
\right]_{3}
=
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|rrrr}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{400}{361} & \frac{24}{361} & -\frac{13}{361} & -\frac{8}{361} \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{64}{19} & \frac{16}{19} & \frac{4}{19} & \frac{1}{19} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{39}{361} & -\frac{24}{361} & \frac{13}{361} & \frac{8}{361} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{72}{361} & -\frac{39}{361} & -\frac{24}{361} & \frac{13}{361} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

---

$$
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 A \\ B \\ C \\ D
\end{array}
\right]
}
=
\mathbf{A}^{-1} b=
\frac{1}{361}
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 400 & 24 & -13 & -8 \\
 1216 & 304 & 76 & 19 \\
 -39 & -24 & 13 & 8 \\
 72 & -39 & -24 & 13 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 0 \\ -1 \\ 29 \\5
\end{array}
\right]
=
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 1 \\ -1 \\ -5 \\ 12
\end{array}
\right]
}
$$